# Rx: get first item, but throw exception when the second item arrives

Tags: system.reactive, rx-py

Using Rx observable stream, is there an effective way to get the first item, complete the source observable, but throw an exception if the second item arrives?
Sounds like not a good situation to use Rx for, but is there a clever way to handle it?

Comment: No, there's not a good way to do this. You cannot complete the source observable after one value and then expect another one to come. If you complete the observable then that's it - it's completed.

Comment: I suspected as much. Does not fit the pattern.
However, I was thinking about a pattern in which you get a first item and stash somewhere, and wait for a timeout before deciding to emit the first item if the second item does not arrive by then.
I just see too many cases where you are pulling the entire result set of a database call before deciding.

This pattern would not be useful with a hot observable, but somewhat cold ones like database cursor.

Comment: That should be fairly easy to workout.

Comment: This is getting close `var query = source.Publish(ss => ss.Take(1).Concat(Observable.Amb(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Select(x => -1), ss.Take(1).Concat(Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception())))));`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is a violation of the `IObservable` Contract, that clearly specifies that no extra items should arrive after either `error` or `complete`. So basically, you are checking for a situation that cannot (or should not) arise.